# Swift : Can I use home and work locations using MapKit?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, swift4, apple-maps

Everyone knows that Maps app can detect your home and work location and it shows you with "maps destination" feature. I am just wondering how it gets our specific location like work and home. Is it because we are stable on some places and it figures out we live here and we work there in specific time?

I'm also wondering that how can we get detected datas from the maps. Is it possible that I can use home and work locations on my app, using `MapKit`?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot, since it’s confidential users data. Only apples map app can use it